# Can't Assign Expression in iOS

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray

I've got an NSMutableArray called Letters, and it contains instances of a UIImageView subclass.  I am trying to loop through them and assign them new values

```
 for (int i=0 ;i<26;i++)
{
    [letters objectAtIndex:i] = [[typeLetters alloc]initWithManager:self atX:startX andY:startY withSideLenght:48 andName:[letterNames objectAtIndex:i] andPng:[letterNames objectAtIndex:i]];
}
```

This doesn't work though. Xcode says "Cannot assign to expression", but when I try to assign new values to each array item individually, outside of the array, it works.  Do you know why this would be?

EDIT: Nevermind.  I'm sorry.  I should have looked into arrays a bit more.

Comment: That's not how you do it.  Read the documentation for NSMutableArray -- PLEASE!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you're looking for is.-

```
- (void)replaceObjectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index withObject:(id)anObject;
```

---

```
for (int i=0 ;i<26;i+=1) {
    [letters replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:[[typeLetters alloc]initWithManager:self atX:startX andY:startY withSideLenght:48 andName:[letterNames objectAtIndex:i] andPng:[letterNames objectAtIndex:i]]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/replaceObjectAtIndex%3awithObject%3a), but you should really use the new array syntax:

```
letters[i] = ...
```

Answer (score 0):

array notation works: `letters[i] = blah`

But you should probably be using fast enumeration:

`for(id letter in letters) {
letter = blah;
}`